# jdk-14.0.1 Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, virtual-machine, java-14

I installed jdk-14.0.1 in my computer and I set Environment variable for that, when I give 
command `java` or `java -version` it gives below exception.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.System.getProperty(java.base/System.java:850)
        at sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction.privilegedGetProperty(java.base/GetPropertyAction.java:105)
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset(java.base/Charset.java:605)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(java.base/StringCoding.java:329)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(java.base/String.java:610)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(java.base/String.java:632)
        at jdk.internal.util.SystemProps$Raw.vmProperties(java.base/Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.util.SystemProps$Raw.cmdProperties(java.base/SystemProps.java:253)
        at jdk.internal.util.SystemProps.initProperties(java.base/SystemProps.java:55)
        at java.lang.System.initPhase1(java.base/System.java:2002)
```

my system configuration is like-

1. Ram: 8.00 GB(7.89 GB usable)
2. OS: windows 10.
3. processor: Intel(R) Core i5-8265U.
4. System type: 64-bit Opearting System, x64-based perocessor.

Comment: What language, codepage etc do you use?

Comment: what is the output of `chcp` on the command line?

Comment: I have been facing this problem ever since I restored my windows. I guess java is unable to get my system's properties during the creation of virtual machine.

Comment: output for chcp command is : Active code page: 65001

Comment: Thanks, that is somewhat expected. You should be able to fix this by going to the control panel -> Region -> "Administrative" tab -> Change system locale -> Uncheck "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide support". After this, restart your system. Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: Yeah It worked. problem has been resolved. Thanks! @JohannesKuhn I am grateful for your support.

Comment: my code page is 936, but it still has the same problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solution for windows 10:**

Open command prompt(CMD)

1. open command prompt.
2. type **chcp** and hit Enter.
3. if output for chcp command is : Active code page: 65001
     **then: go to the control panel -> Region -> "Administrative" tab -> Change system locale -> Uncheck "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide support".**
4. Restart your PC.
5. Again check system local for 'beta' if it is unchecked then all is ok.
6. if it is checked again then try to change your native language to English.

Answer (score 1):

This can* happen if you have the default locale to Codepage 65001 - UTF-8.

To "fix" this on Windows 10:

- Open the control panel
- Select "Region"
- Go to the "Administrative" tab
- Click on the "Change system locale" button
- Uncheck "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide support".
- Save. You should get a prompt to restart your computer. Do that.

* It should not, however.

Answer (score 0):

For those whoes code page is not 65001 but come acorss the same problem. Suggest try openjdk 14. It works for me.